# Asymptotic time complexity of recursive function (Theta)

Tags: recursion, time, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I have been asked to analyze the asymptotic time complexity of the following recursion function:

```
for-all k ≥ 1:
T(n) = n + T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8) + .... + T(n/2^k)
```

I was able to prove that:
`T(n) = O(n⋅log n)` and `T(n) =  Ω(n)`,
but I am looking for a tighter bound (Big Theta).

Comment: Your formula reads as if the expression for `T` is infinite - is that correct?

Comment: The function is not infinite, as the last addend is `T(n/2^k)`.

Comment: Yet `k` is not bounded, as you wrote yourself: "for-all k >= 1"

Comment: Yes, but we need a solution for any given k.

Comment: So, you're looking at a family of functions, Tk, and for each of these families, k is a constant?

Comment: Honestly i don't know, judging from the way the problem is formulated it's not clear whether they are asking for a general solution or a family of solutions of each given k, what is described above is the entire problem.

Comment: I agree with your bounds (`n*log(n)` for k->inf, `2n-1` for k = 1), however I am unable to find anything for the sums in between. Wolfram and Matlab don't really provide anything either. By the results I was able to get, it is *neither linear, nor log-linear*. You may have better luck in Mathematics.SE - this question isn't really about programming

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
I understand "*for-all k >= 1*" this way: for `k = 1` to `k = m` where `2m-1 ≤ n ≤ 2m`.
So basicly `m = log₂(n)` holds.

Have a look at my calculation:

```
T(n) = n + Σk=1,...,m T(n/2k)
     = n + T(n/2) + Σk=2,...,m T(n/2k)
     = n +  n/2 + 2⋅Σk=2,...,m T(n/2k)
     = ...
     = n + Σk=1,...,m k⋅n/2k
     = n + n⋅Σk=1,...,m k/2k
     = n + n⋅(2 - 2-mm - 21-m)
     ≤ n + 2⋅n
     = 3n
```

So `T(n)` is in `Θ(n)`.

Notice:
You can also approximate `Σk=1,...,m k/2k` by the integral  `s(m) = ∫1m k/2k dk`.
And here `limm → ∞s(m) = 2` also holds.